# I'm adding a service worker to WordPress but cannot stop it adding Wordpress files to the cache

Tags: javascript, wordpress, caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm creating a service worker for my WordPress install. I'm defining a list of files to cache in my sw.js file but when refreshing the page, WordPress appears to be loading in lots of additional files.

This wouldn't be a problem normally but it means that some of the admin files are being cached which is stopping users editing content.

Here's the code. The sw.js file is in the root of Wordpress. The file named 'test.css' is also in the root for testing purposes.

Any help - much appreciated!

-Steve

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var filesToCache = [
      'test.css' 
  ];

  var staticCacheName = 'pages-cache-v1.0.1';

  self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    console.log('Attempting to install service worker and cache static assets');
    event.waitUntil(
      caches.open(staticCacheName)
      .then(function(cache) {
        console.log(filesToCache);
        return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
      })
    );
  });

  self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    //console.log('Fetch event for ', event.request.url);
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
        if (response) {
          //console.log('Found ', event.request.url, ' in cache');
          return response;
        }
        //console.log('Network request for ', event.request.url);
        return fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
          return caches.open(staticCacheName).then(function(cache) {
            if (event.request.url.indexOf('test') < 0) {
              cache.put(event.request.url, response.clone());
            }
            return response;
          });
        });
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Error, ', error);
      })
    );
  });

  self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
    //console.log('Activating new service worker...');

    var cacheWhitelist = [staticCacheName];
    event.waitUntil(
      caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
        return Promise.all(
          cacheNames.map(function(cacheName) {
            console.log(cacheNames);
            if (cacheWhitelist.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
              return caches.delete(cacheName);
            }
          })
        );
      })
    );
  });

})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to make sure, your problem is that too much is cached, right?

If that's the case, look at your code. If it doesn't find something in its cache, it fetches it from the network *and* puts it in the cache. That's the only put operation in the code.

You have to same problem explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47571254/service-worker-caches-to-much/47617328#47617328).

The flow of the code is new to anyone starting out with Service Workers but it's actually pretty straightforward come to think of it. You can just read it and it tells you what it's doing. Look at the line where you have a put in the code. Look at the surroundings of that line. What's happening?

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much. The link above had some great information. The issue was to do with the fetch function.